# Im using c# for a windows app , i want to use a arraylist , but i have system.collections in but it stil will not work

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi I am trying to create a windows app in vs 2013, I want to use an array list, I do have `system.collections` in but it will not find array list what is the problem ?.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `List<T>` instead.  `ArrayList` is not available in Windows runtime.

[MSDN: List Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Remember to include

```C#
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList is not available for `Windows phone` or you can say for  `> .net 3.0` .

They have removed and put the generic collections so you can possibly use a different collection class instead?  Perhaps the `List<T>` type?

And System.Collections namespace for Metro Style applications lacks of ArrayList type.